# React Native - Extra space in header when nesting Stack Navigator in Material Top Tab Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In this application, I am using navigators provided by `react-navigation` with the following hierarchy.

```
BottomTabNavigator
    |
    + StackNavigator
    |
    + MaterialTopTabNavigator (PageTopTabNav)
    |     |
    |     + StackNavigator (StackNavA)
    |     |
    |     + StackNavigator
    |     |
    |     + StackNavigator
    |
    + StackNavigator
```

In the screenshot below, the area boxed in red is not configurable, the only way to get rid of it is to set `header: null` in my `StackNavigator`.

```
const StackNavA = createStackNavigator({
  LandingA: { screen: ScreenLandingA },
  Details: { screen: ScreenDetails }
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
});
```

However, I want to show the navigation bar, so as to keep the back button in place to allow users going back to previous page.

This `StackNavA` is exported as follows.

```
export default class ScreenA extends React.Component {
  static router = StackNavA.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <StackNavA navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    );
  }
}
```

It is being used by a `MaterialTopTabNavigator` from another file.

```
const PageTopTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  A: { screen: ScreenA },
  B: { screen: ScreenB },
  C: { screen: ScreenC }
}, {
  initialRouteName: "A",
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "white",
    inactiveTintColor: "#CCCCCC",
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      height: 0
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "teal",
      borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
      borderBottomColor: "gray"
    }
  },
  backBehavior: "none"
});
```

`PageTopTabNav` is exported wrapped by a `SafeAreaView` component to prevent overlapping with the status bar in **iOS** devices.

```
export default class BrowseScreen extends React.Component {
  static router = PageTopTabNav.router;

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "teal" }}>
        <PageTopTabNav navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get rid of the area boxed in red while keeping the navigation bar in `StackNavA`?

[image: area-in-question]

Answer (score 2):

Use the headerMode: none configuration param to disappear it.

```
export default StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: Login.component }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
    headerMode: 'none' <------------- This
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarOptions: {
 ...,
 safeAreaInset: { bottom: 'never', top: 'never' }  // <-- this is the solution
}
```

for ios issue of tan navigation extra bottom spaces